# Get a require user and password from database by result set

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection, resultset

```
String user=usertx.getText();
    char[] password=pswdtx.getPassword();
    String pswd=String.valueOf(password);   \\here is important to put a char password in string.
```

1- We call the require user and his password by:

```
Resultset rs= stmt.excuteQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME='"+user+"' AND PASSWORD='"+pswd+"'");
```

This code will get only the row of selected user and his information on row and set it in (rs).

2- Code of rs.next():

```
while(rs.next()){
     rsuser=rs.getString("NAME");      //get user and set it in rsuser.
     rspswd=rs.getString("PASSWORD");} //get password and set it in rspswd.

if ((user.equals(rsuser)) && (pswd.equals(rspswd))){  //the equevlant statement.
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password exist");}
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check Username and Password ");}
        }
```

here is whole of code:

```
private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    try {
        String user=usertx.getText();
        char[] password=pswdtx.getPassword();
        String pswd=String.valueOf(password);

        String rsuser=null;
        String rspswd=null;
        String Q="SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME='"+user+"' AND PASSWORD='"+pswd+"'";
        rs=stmt.executeQuery(Q);

        while(rs.next()){
        rsuser=rs.getString("NAME");
        rspswd=rs.getString("PASSWORD");}
        if ((user.equals(rsuser)) && (pswd.equals(rspswd))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and Password exist");}
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Check Username and Password ");}
        } 
    catch (SQLException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}`

}
```

With my best wishes.

Comment: This code has a big chance to be affected by SQL injection.

Comment: thanx  for atention @MikeCAT

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: its not question,its Q&A

Comment: Please divide your article to *question* and *answer* to share your knowledge.

Comment: To clarify what MikeCAT said about the Q&A: On SO, you are allowed to post things in a Q&A, given that the question is in the question area, and the answer is not found within the question, but rather in the answer section (text box for entry is below the comments). Otherwise, this doesn't exactly fit the community guidelines. More information can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer